# MongoDB: Problemas con UTC

Tags: mongodb, date, nosql, pipeline

Estoy intentando diseñar un parámetro para evitar que en la recarga automática nocturna que hace el dataset de mi aplicación BI no se incorporen registros del día en curso.

Tengo la siguiente consulta de prueba:

```
var pipeline = 
[
    {
        "$match": 
        {
            "idDevice": 2353,
            "data.inicio": {"$exists": true},
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": 
        {
            "fecha": {"$toDate": "$data.inicio"},
            "fechaAhora": {"$toDate": {"$dateToString": {"format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$$NOW", "timezone": "Europe/Madrid"}}},
        }
    },
    /*{
      "$match":
      {
          "fecha": {"$lt": "$fechaAhora"}
      }
    },*/
    {
        "$project":
        {
            "_id": 0,
            "fechaC": "$data.inicio",
            "fecha": "$fecha",
            "fechaAhora": "$fechaAhora",
        }
    },
]

db.sensorsData.aggregate(pipeline)
```

El primer documento que aparece:

```
{
  "fechaC": "2022-02-02T00:00:00+01:00",
  "fecha": "2022-02-01T23:00:00.000Z",
  "fechaAhora": "2022-02-17T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Y tal como lo veo yo en el software que utilizo, NoSQL Booster:

[image: NoSQL Booster]

Tengo ciertas dudas con el manejo de las fechas que hace Mongo:

`"data.inicio"`, o `"fechaC"`, es una fecha -o lo que un humano entiende por una fecha- en formato cadena, las 00:00 hora de Madrid (+1 UTC), con lo cual serían las 23:00 en UTC. A mí no me interesa trabajar en UTC, sino en la hora de Madrid. Si algo ocurre a las 00:00 hora de Madrid me da igual que en UTC sean las 23:00 del día anterior: ese hecho ocurrió, para mí y para los clientes para los que trabajo, ya a las 00:00 del nuevo día y así quiero que quede reflejado en mi dataset.

Si transformas `"fechaC"` en un objeto de tipo fecha (`"fecha"`) con `$toDate`, NoSQL Booster muestra las 00:00 hora de Madrid, lo que yo espero, pero en el JSON aparecen las 23:00, la hora UTC, con la que no quiero trabajar.

Por otro lado, el parámetro que he creado para que muestre el inicio del día actual, `"fechaAhora"`, al que le he incorporado `"timezone": "Europe/Madrid"` -aunque si no lo hago el resultado es el mismo, por cierto-, NoSQL Booster lo muestra como 1:00 -no sé por qué, yo esperaría que aparecieran simplemente las 00:00- aunque el JSON lo hace como 00:00 -que en realidad es lo que me interesaría, aunque supongo que se trata de la hora UTC, con lo cual no es con la que quiero trabajar-.

¿Por qué este baile de cifras? ¿Estoy cargando las fechas tal y como me interesa en mi dataset -es decir, con la hora en la que trabajo, la de Madrid- o me las está convirtiendo a UTC y estoy falseando los registros?

**EDICIÓN**

He cargado un único documento en el dataset de mi aplicación BI -haciendo uso de `"$limit": 1`- para ver qué aspecto tiene:

```
fechaC 2022-02-02T00:00:00+01:00 
fecha 2022/02/01 23:00
fechaAhora 2022/02/17 00:00
```

`fechaC` se carga tal cual, las 00:00, como es esperable, porque es una cadena; `fecha` lo hace en formato UTC, las 23:00 del día anterior, y `fechaAhora` lo hace como espero, en el momento de inicio del día.

Es decir, esto es equivalente al JSON que obtengo a partir de NoSQL Booster; ni idea de por qué su interfaz gráfica es diferente.

El problema que tengo, entiendo, es conseguir que `fecha` se cargue con la hora local de Madrid, las 00:00, y no en UTC, las 23:00 del día anterior. La función `$toDate` creo que no admite `"timezone": "Europe/Madrid"`.

**EDICIÓN 2:**

Veo que hay otro campo fecha en estos documentos que sí viene en formato `date`:

```
  "dateTime": 
  {
    "instant":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1644102000000"}},
    "offset":"+01:00"
  },
```

Frente a este otro que venía usando y que viene en formato `string`:

```
  "data":
  {
    "inicio":"2022-02-06T00:00:00+01:00",
    "fin":"2022-02-06T00:00:10+01:00",
  }
```

El aspecto de ambos en Compass:

[image: Compass]

Modifico la consulta:

```
var pipeline = 
[
    {
        "$match": 
        {
            /*"idDevice": 2353,
            "data.inicio": {"$exists": true},*/
            "_id": ObjectId("61ff049260805d1b17f0307c"),
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": 
        {
            "fechaD": "$dateTime.instant",
            "fechaSD": {"$toDate": "$data.inicio"},
            "fechaAhora": {"$toDate": {"$dateToString": {"format": "%Y-%m-%d", "date": "$$NOW", "timezone": "Europe/Madrid"}}},
        }
    },
    /*{
      "$match":
      {
          "fecha": {"$lt": "$fechaAhora"}
      }
    },*/
    {
        "$project":
        {
            "fechaS": "$data.inicio",
            "fechaSD": "$fechaSD",
            "fechaD": "$fechaD",
            "fechaAhora": "$fechaAhora",
        }
    },
    {
        "$limit": 1
    }
]

db.sensorsData.aggregate(pipeline)
```

El interfaz gráfico de NoSQL Booster los muestra así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en formato JSON:

```
{
  "_id": "61ff049260805d1b17f0307c",
  "fechaS": "2022-02-06T00:00:00+01:00",
  "fechaSD": "2022-02-05T23:00:00.000Z",
  "fechaD": "2022-02-05T23:00:00.000Z",
  "fechaAhora": "2022-02-21T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Que es como se carga en mi BI.

Supongo que tendría que añadir `dateTime.offset` a `dateTime.instant` para obtener la hora local...

Comment: No, debes acostumbrarte a trabajar y utilizar UTC. No existe ninguna forma de obligar a MongoDB a almacenar datos de tipo Date en otra zona horaria distinta a UTC. MongoDB usa Javascript por debajo, y la implementación de Javascript para el objeto Date establece su uso en hora UTC.

Comment: En caso de que trabajes con distintos husos, bien, ¿pero si siempre trabajas en el mismo? Esto va a ser un cuadro de mandos con emisiones de vídeo, así que le estoy diciendo a mi cliente que vídeos que realmente se emitieron a las 00 de un día lo hicieron a las 23 del anterior.

Comment: No importa el Huso horario, a eso me refiero. Acostumbra a guardar las fechas en formato Date y no tendrás estos problemas de Husos, ya sea que ejecutes tu aplicación en Madrid o en Pekin, da igual donde estés, siempre que el valor de fecha se almacene en UTC. Tú por el contrario almacenas una cadena con timezone, si vas a trabajar con cadenas no uses Date, ya que suceden este tipo de problemas.

Comment: Ya, desgraciadamente no soy el administrador de la BD.